# Force Java compiler to assume that all variables are final

Tags: java, functional-programming

Is it possible -- via a compiler switch or a commonly used tool (which I do not know) -- to break a compilation if a variable is reassigned when not marked as a mutable keyword (which is not present in Java yet)?

Example:

```
Contract a; // compile error
Contract b = getContract(id); // ok
b.doSomething(); // ok
b = getContract(otherId); // compile error
mutable int i = 1;
i++; // ok
```

I know that there are languages are like this, but being forced to code java in a company, using such a tool is the only choice.

Greetings,
JG.

Comment: Google's errorprone has a check for this: http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/Var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't force a Java compiler to do that.   And you can't put non-Java keywords (like `mutable`) into Java source code.  No compliant Java compiler will allow either of these.

You could possibly use a custom annotation to "declare" mutable local variables, and use a static analyser to detect assignments to locals without the annotation.

There may even be existing analyser tools, annotations, etc that will do this for you, though I am not aware of a tool that exactly fits the bill.

(The `FinalLocalVariable` check for CheckStyle doesn't do exactly what you want.   It will tell you where to add `final` to declarations, but that isn't what you are asking for ... I think.  You want variables to be *treated* as `final` even if they are not explicitly declared as such.)

---

But in my opinion, it would be a bad idea to do this.

Your employer has made a decision (right or wrong) that Java is the only language you can use.  One of the reasons for this will ensuring that the code that you develop can be maintained and enhanced by Java programmers.  By using unusual notations so that you can write zero-assignment code, you are undermining company policy.

At best, you won't make yourself popular with your coworkers by doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [CheckStyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html#FinalLocalVariable) static code analysis tool. You can also integrate it to your IDE.
`FinalLocalVariable` check looks like your case:

> Checks that local variables that never have their values changed are
>   declared final. The check can be configured to also check that
>   unchanged parameters are declared final.

Also there is [PMD](https://pmd.github.io/) source code analyzer. But I've never used it so cannot suggest anything.